# What is the inverse of the divisor sum function $\sigma $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $(A, +, *)$ be the commutative ring of arithmetic functions with Dirichlet convolution as the multiplicative operation *.

The element $$\sigma(n)=\prod_i \frac{p_i^{k_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}, \text { where } n=\prod_i p_i^{k_i}$$ has a multiplicative inverse because $\sigma(1)=1$. Using the recursive definition (Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Theorem 2.8 ) of the multiplicative inverse of an arithmetic function I found the following definition for $\sigma^{-1} $ : 
$$\sigma^{-1}(n)=\prod_i f(p_i^{k_i}) \text { where }
f(p_i^{k_i}) = \begin{cases} -p_i-1 &\mbox{if } k_i = 1 \\ 
p_i & \mbox{if } k_i = 2 \\
0 & \mbox{if } k_i > 2. \end{cases}$$

Question: is there a shorter (computable) definition of $\sigma^{-1}$ than the one I gave above, preferably without the if cases and multiplicative notation as the one Apostol gave for the totient function. $$\varphi^{-1}=\prod_i (1-p_i).$$

Comment: Is Apostol's Theorem 2.20 any better?

Comment: I will work further on it using t2.20, i am looking for the multiplicative version of the function. The 2.20 might just help.

Comment: Edited the question: reference to inverse for totient function, I am looking for such a description but for sigma in my case. Will work on tip from @Daniel later today.

Comment: Would you prefer $\mu(n) *n\mu(n)$?  It isn't any more computable, but it is shorter.

Comment: @ErickWong: that's theorem 2.20 (in the one-line proof).

Comment: Thanks. Found that one in Apostol, Erick. I basically want a computable one in multiplicative notation.

Comment: I have one already. .. but it is ugly.

Comment: @ndroock1: is the object still to show that $\sigma*\sigma^{-1}= I?$

Comment: @daniel secundary, as a proof that the Inverse function Is correct. That is why I removed that part from the question.

Comment: @ndroock1 I'm unclear on what you mean by computable. What is non-computable about any of these formulas?

Comment: @erick wong. Computable is not a good word choice, I apologise. What I meant was no usage of number theoretic functions like Moebius, totient, sigma, etc. Only primes, exponents and algebraic operators. I gave one solution already myself, but I don't like the way it is defined, too many if ' s. I wonder if someone has a better definition, that is all. My solution "does not look right", if you know what I mean.

Comment: I wonder if the title shouldn't be changed. You are looking for something very specific and neither the title nor the question make it clear exactly what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question still doesn't make much sense.  The inverse is *unique*, and you want a multiplicative definition so you are really asking to describe $\sigma^{-1}$ at each prime power.  So I don't see how this has anything to do with number theory: you're just asking if there is a simpler way to write the function $f(p^k)$ even though you already know that $f(p^k)$ is exactly equal to
$$\begin{cases} -p-1, &\mbox{if } k = 1; \\ 
p, & \mbox{if } k = 2; \\
0, & \mbox{if } k > 2. \end{cases}$$

Within these constraints there is little you can expect to do besides trivial rearrangements such as $f(p^k) = \mu(p^k) - p \cdot\mu(p^{k-1})$ (only for $k \ge 1$).  But this is morally equivalent to hiding if statements into indicator functions.  I would say that your sense that it "does not look right" is misguided: the function is what it is.

Comment: I like that improvement, makes sense to me. And no more ifs. (Don't start me on ifless coding.) The power of math is often to be found in the notation.